# How can I efficiently record video of my game on android?

Tags: android

I am trying to record screen on device. How can I do it efficiently?
This will be a feature of my game so I don't want to go for options that just work in debug mode.

Comment: Given the extreme lockdown of Android, a practical approach to this problem will actually be quite narrow.  This version of the question which states the requirement is much more productive than the alternate attempt which pursues an unworkable idea.